# Composer autoloader, github and deployment

Tags: php, github, deployment, ftp, composer-php

I am sorry if this has been asked before but after searching for a while I couldn't really find answers to my dilemma.

I am part of team that is working on a PHP project and we use github for our version control. We would like to implement a PSR-4 autoloader and every single guide uses Composer so we would as well. Now, while searching I learned that the vendor folder should not be included into github, but only the composer.json and that every developer needs to install composer onto their own computer.

Does that require the autoloader to be created again on every developers computer.

And finally, when the project is done, we would like to upload it onto our website, but the only way we can do that is through FTP.

Which files should be uploaded to the live website and what would happen to th autoloader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to commit the composer.lock file as well. That's super-important - it means that whenever someone else checks out the code they get the same set of dependencies (including their exact versions) installed to their /vendor directory.

That's why you don't need the /vendor directory to be committed - the lock file takes care of ensuring the dependencies are fixed.

The composer.json defines numerous potential versions of your dependencies that meet your requirements. Running `composer update` essentially checks to see if a more recent version is available that meets those requirements. That's the difference between install and update - install goes off the lock file and knows exactly what to look for - update goes off the json file and could return different results at different points in time.

In your composer.json you can define the autoloader by telling it where your root namespace lives.

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "RootNamespace\\": "library/src"
    }
},
```

When your colleagues have run `composer install` it will create the autoloader for them in a consistent path.

You have options for deployment:

You can either upload the composer.lock file and run a composer install on production, or do it ahead of time and upload your vendor directory as part of the build.

I do the latter as I would prefer if there was an issue at this point to know about it *before* any files are changed on the production server. The alternative could leave a botched upgrade on production with missing dependencies. Safer to install those dependencies first and transfer everything in one go.

As an aside, I also like to install a fresh release to a separate folder on production named after the git commit and then symlink it as part of the deployment step. This ensures you don't have a half-updated application whilst you wait for the rest of the files to be uploaded. This approach would also eliminate the issue mentioned before, meaning you could do your composer install from production.

Comment: Just an extra note about the `composer.lock`. It doesn't just make sure you get the same dependencies, but also the exact same versions (just thought it was worth pointing out). Also, before uploading the files to the productions server, run: `composer install --no-dev --optimize-autoloader` to make sure you only get the relevant packages (ignoring dev-packages) and an optimized autoloader (it doesn't need to search the IO trying to look for classes).

Comment: Yep that's what I meant (regarding versions) but I wasn't specific enough - thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Symlinks FTW . It also makes it easy to revert to the previous version, if needed.